# Carousel jumps using mySwipe

Tags: javascript, swipe

I have 4 bullets points, and I noticed the function callback and transitionEnd fire twice. So the carousel jumps some slide...I don't understand why. `window.mySwipe` is initialized once.

```
 <script src="js/swipe-slider.js"></script>
 <script>
    window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
   startSlide: 0,
   speed: 400,
   auto: 2000,
   continuous: true,
   disableScroll: false,
   stopPropagation: true,
   callback: function(index, elem) {
    console.log("callback: " + index);
   },
   transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {
    console.log("-");
   }
  });
 </script>
```

OUTPUT CONSOLE :

[image: capture d ecran 2015-01-08 a 12 03 18]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I removed `auto: 2000` and I used a recursive function by calling `window.mySwipe.next();`. Now, no jumps anymore.